# How to write regex for the following experssions to split the data

Tags: python, regex, split

1 - Supr Senior: M66tzer, Bill)
first_name= Bilr '(' as first name = Roger and last name= Dell..for any string it shuld read till ( and split the name as first name and last name how to write regex

Comment: Welcome to SO! Unfortunately, this is [off topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)--there are many ways to do this. Can you post a [mcve] showing what you've tried and where you got stuck? Thanks.

Comment: can u help me to split

Comment: You inverted `f_name` and `l_name` of Joseph Bannet.

Comment: Can u tell for the updated question how to have the regex expression

Comment: You seem to have damaged your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It should support all the above cases

The below code does. It doesn't use [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split), but [`search()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) and *capturing parentheses*.

```
for case in ''' Pocatello, ID/ (Habashi, Yashar)
 Idaho Falls, ID/ (Pigott, Joseph)
 orian flex joy, Lex/ (Bannet, Joseph)'''.split('\n'):
    l_name, f_name = re.search(r'\((.*), (.*)\)', case).group(1, 2)
```

Comment: This worked well,I need to join now the full_name as Yashar habashi,joseph pigott,joseph bannet how to join the full name

Comment: when I tried I get '(Bannet, Joseph)' with this '( all but i need full name as Bannet Joseph

Comment: One way to join is `fullname = ' '.join((f_name, l_name))`.

Comment: Are you really sure that it's not rather _l_name_ _Bannet_, _f_name_ _Joseph_ and _m_name_ _Alex_?

Comment: I have updated my question can u pls tell the regex for that condition

Comment: The code I already posted works just as well for the updated question.

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group' i  get this error

Comment: Can u tell me how to fix that attribute error

Comment: I can only tell that if you show the code and data you use; it cannot be my code with the two data lines you posted.

Comment: Houston, TX/ (Poston III, Carl)
Crp Christi, TX/ (Justice, Larry) how to handle this case
l_name as poston III f_name as Carl
l-nam as justice f_name as larry

Comment: The code I already posted works just as well for these cases (provided the two are on separate lines).

Comment: instead of using groups can u suggest me separate regex for f_name and last_name

Comment: Why unnecessarily complicate things by not using groups?

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group' i get this error bcz of this

Comment: You should repair your question, showing the data you use when getting this error.